# how to store previous 7 days data in db?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to create simple kind of stats for a page. How can I store the number of hits of last 7 days in the database? I just need an idea about how to store only previous 7 days data in the database. Something like:

- February3: 10
- February2: 11
- Febraury1: 10
- January31: 1

and so on?

Do I need to make like 7 columns to store each days hits number or I can manage with one column?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you add another table

- pageID - foreign key to your page table (or some other reference)
- date
- hits

and store one row per page per day. You can then delete all rows from this table where date is > 7 days old as a daily job.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to just store every visit to your database and select the COUNT() of the last 7 days.
Or you could make an extra table that has 1 row for every day and just select the last 7 days with INTERVAL() function.

Comment: Actually yes we've done the store-every-visit way before. The problem with that is that the table can get very large, and then it gets very slow to query / aggregate. We ended up adding an hourly job to run statistics on the table into an aggregated visit table and then reported from the aggregated table. However if you only keep 7 days worth of data it might stay managable, and we were recording / reporting a lot more than just visits.

Comment: I think that if your query is starting to get too slow there is either something wrong with the index or the server. In my experience even tables with 10^6 rows are still searchable with acceptable timing (< 1 second).